# How to define an array of const pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, constants

Is there a way to define an array of pointers so that any pointer is const?

For example, can a `char** array` be defined so `array[0]` is const and `array[1]` is const, etc., but `array` is non-const and `array[j][i]` is non-const?

Comment: I know this may be slightly unrelated to the question, but any reason you want to use arrays rather than STL containers (i.e std::vector)?

Comment: @AliAlamiri: the STL has `std::array`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It does indeed. Still would advise using containers though in practice, unless there is no way around it.

Comment: Some misconception here... Your type in `char** array` is not an array (not a C styled array); it is a pointer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`char* const * pointer;`. then

```
pointer       -> non-const pointer to const pointer to non-const char (char* const *)
pointer[0]    -> const pointer to non-const char (char* const)
pointer[0][0] -> non-const char
```

If you want an array then `char* const array[42] = { ... };`.

If you don't know the size of array at compile-time and have to allocate the array at run-time, you could use the pointer then

```
int n = ...;
char* const * pointer = new char* const [n] { ... };
...
delete[] pointer;
```

As you can see, you have to perform allocation and deallocation manually. Even you've said you don't want `std::vector` but for mordern C++ using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) is more appropriate.

Comment: And if I don't want to declare about the array's size from the beginning? for example, if I want in the following of the code to allocate this array (by `new` , yes, I know that it is not appropriate to c++, but, any way, I want.) , so How can I define `array` as `array`? (Namely, what I can doing in case that I don't know the size of the array from the beginning, and I don't want to use `std::vector` !!)

Comment: @StackUser Then you have to use pointer and `new[]`. e.g. `char* const * pointer = new char* const [42] { ... };`. At last, even you've said you don't want `std::vecto`: but for mordern C++ using `std::vector` is more appropriate.

Comment: and `42` is the size of any "string" in this case?

Comment: @StackUser It's the size of the array, which will contain 42 elements.

Comment: So in case that I don't know what is the size of the array, I can set there `n` (instead `42`) for example? (while `n` is something that I get as input  - for example.)

Comment: @StackUser Yes.

Comment: On "`std::vector<char* const>`", standard containers behave poorly when given `const` elements to work with. You can't insert/remove in the middle, or perform a variety of other operations.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's true. The same issues happens with raw array, constants can't be modified or moved. This might depend on OP's real application scenario.

Comment: The dynamic sizing is useless -- you need an initializer list in order to give the elements (non-default) values because they can never again be changed, and having an initializer list will determine the size at compile time.

Comment: @BenVoigt: not quite.  `push_back` and `pop_back` work fine with `const` elements.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I'm talking about the `new const T[n]` construction in the answer

Answer (score 14):

For such a request you can use the magic tool `cdecl` (also available as a web UI [here](https://cdecl.org/)):

```
$ cdecl -+ %c++ mode
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> declare x as array of const pointer to char
char * const x[]
cdecl>
```

Comment: Does the web UI have a C++ mode flag?